# unable to update bundle when update core whith karaf

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, blueprint-osgi

I meet a big concern, I have several bundle.

As

- bundlecore
- bundleui
- bundleaddoncore

bundleui needs bundlecore,
bundleaddoncore needs bundlecore

When I update bundlecore with karaf, I noticed that bundleui and bundleaddoncore still using the old version? I must restart Karaf? Is this normal? if so what is the right way to recharge the dependent bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to restart Karaf this is typical for OSGi. The Other bundles still use the old services or reference the "old" classes. After a bundle update you need to refresh the depending bundles, only with this your bundles do get resolved again and therefore use the new bundle. 
To do so you either call refresh  or just refresh in the Karaf console.